Please improve the UX for ignoring tags
Since the "ignore" choice on tag pop-ups is no longer available, the only way I can find to ignore tags is:

navigate to the questions page (if not already there)
select "edit" from the "ignored tags" list
type in the tag name
press "add"
go back to the page I was viewing or, more likely, scroll up ten empty screens to get back to where I started on the page

This is terrible.
Please improve the UX to be as convenient as the original "ignore" links were.

"go back to the page I was viewing or, more likely, scroll up ten empty screens to get back to where I started on the page" - this one stumps me. Ten pages worth of empty content? Where are those coming from?

@Gimby after "add", the ignore tag list expands, the viewport moves to keep the entry box (at the bottom) visible. 500+ tags at 3-4 per line is a lot of lines - much longer than the 20(?) questions on the page

A better flow, where the button still exists, is just clicking on the tag to go to its respective tag search page, where there's an "ignore" button at the top of the screen. But that's still a worse flow than it used to be, and still quite unintuitive.

@zcoop98 that would be acceptable although still horrible, but the pages I assume you mean (questions/tagged/foo) now just show me a "follow tag" button

@zcoop98 it's not. for group C. Group B is the same.

@VLAZ Well dang. I didn't realize there was still an ongoing experiment... removing the out-of-the-way button there doesn't seem to make any sense at all.

I cannot even ignore a tag this way because I will get a HTTP 500 service call response error when I try. So instead I have to go to the profile page, go to "Settings", click on the "Tag watching & ignoring" menu item (which apparently is an "email setting", even though I don't receive any emails from SO...), scroll down to the ignore list, click on "Add a tag", enter the tag and click on "Ignore tag". An action which previously took 1 second and 1 click is now a ~15 second 5 click action (and include 3 page changes). That is definitely not an improvement.

@jhnc Ah that's the detail I was missing, you have a huge list of ignored tags. Yeah that's why I'm all for bypassing that feature altogether because to have any kind of use out of my homepage I'd have to do the same but I really don't want to do that kind of micro management. Me personally I don't want to see tags on my home page if they're not on my watch list.
